# how to use if isset() with symfony and post parameters

Tags: php, symfony, post, parameters

in the flat php I can just writing this line like that

```
if(isset($_POST['MoveString'])){

//code here 


}
```

but in symfony when I write my code like that

```
if(isset($request->get('MoveString'))){

//my code here

}
```

I get this error

```
Compile Error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)
```

so what's the wrong aren't they the same result ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

according to this part of [isset documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php#refsect1-function.isset-notes) :

> #### Warning
>
> isset() only works with variables as passing anything else will result
>   in a parse error.

and where is the result of expression in your code ?

to figure out this, take a quick look at the implementation of [`Request\get`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.php#L791) method :

```
public function get($key, $default = null)
{
    if ($this !== $result = $this->attributes->get($key, $this)) {
        return $result;
    }
    if ($this !== $result = $this->query->get($key, $this)) {
        return $result;
    }
    if ($this !== $result = $this->request->get($key, $this)) {
        return $result;
    }
    return $default;
}
```

and as you can see, for example from the [`ParameterBag`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/ParameterBag.php#L86) object which is called via `$this->attributes` property, and you can check the other properties [ query, request ]'s objects too.

$result is returning a result of an expression

```
public function get($key, $default = null)
{
    return array_key_exists($key, $this->parameters) ? $this->parameters[$key] : $default;
}
```

---

so you simply needs to -as the error explains- to use your statement as follows:

```
if($request->get('MoveString') !== null){

//my code here

}
```

or even simpler :

```
if($request->get('MoveString')){

//my code here

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to know if the parameter exists, even with a `null` value, you can use the `has()` method instead of `get()`:

```
if ($request->has('MoveString')){

     //my code here

}
```